# What is the exact process for URL rewriting and redirecting in htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

I am completely new to building websites and want to understand the process for URL rewriting and redirecting as the rules I am including in my htaccess files are not all working and I feel I am missing sth very obvious in here.

I have tried to read Apache documentation however i just can't fully understand it being new to coding - hopefully someone will be able to point me in the right direction.

I have rewritten my URL so I could change the way the URL is displayed in the browser and make it more user/SEO friendly - basically removed .html using below code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^skills$ skills.html [NC,L]
```

The rule above is working perfectly and displaying nice clean URL.

Now to avoid duplicated URL's (Screaming Fog shows now duplicated URL: skills and skills.html) I want to do 301 redirect with the below:

```
Redirect 301 /skills.html https://www.youmedigital.com/skills
```

The problem I am getting now is: too many redirects, across all browsers. I understand that this issue usually happens when you are redirected from the original URL to a new one but unfortunately fall in to an infinite redirect loop. I tried to fix it by clearing my cookies as per online tutorials but it doesn't help.

Can you please help me to understand:
1. Do I need to first rewrite URL before 301 redirecting it as per above? or there is no need to rewrite URL first and just do 301 redirect - I tried both solutions and none of them worked.
2. Do my rules above are correct as i have feeling that maybe the error I'm getting just shows i messed up.

I have included below everything I have in my htaccess file:

```
#Rewrite everything to https
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#301 redirect to www
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^youmedigital.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.youmedigital.com/$1 [L,R=301]

#301 rewrite url and 301 redirect for clean URL
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^skills$ skills.html [NC,L]

Redirect 301 /skills.html http://www.youmedigital.com/skills

#remove index.html and kill the chance of homepage having duplicates
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.(php|html) [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ http://www.youmedigital.com/ [R=301,L]

#remove php and kill the chance of having duplicates
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Thank you for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Let me go throug your code then show you why you get looping :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^skills$ skills.html [NC,L]
```

line above will match this request `http://yourdomain.com/skills` so , it will be redirected to `http://yourdomain.com/skills.html` just adding extension.

At your second rule :

```
Redirect 301 /skills.html https://www.youmedigital.com/skills
```

What you do is match this request `http://yourdomain.com/skills.html` so , it will be redirected to `http://yourdomain.com/skills` so , i think right now you know why looping happened , when first rule applied the second will start and vise versa.

To avoid that , try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /skills\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /skills [NC,L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^skills$   /skills\.html [L]
```

That code above will catch `http://yourdomain.com/skills.html` request and redirect it to `http://yourdomain.com/skills` externally then redirect `http://yourdomain.com/skills` request to `http://yourdomain.com/skills.html` but internally .

Clear your browser cache then test it .

Comment: Thank you so so much Mohammed! You really helped me a lot in here. It works perfectly! I have given you a vote however not displayed as don't have yet any reputation :-(